# Does it matter (performance wise) if we pass integer or Boolean variables by reference?

Tags: c++

Passing values as const reference in function arguments is necessary to avoid creating copies for large objects. Since built-in types like `int` and `bool` are a few bytes in size, do we need to pass them by reference?

Comment: Maybe it matters.  Maybe it doesn't.  To determine if it matters for you code, you will need to **profile** your optimized code, and determine if one or the other approach is a material improvement in performance.

Comment: It is better to pass them by value.  The compiler *might* optimise a (`const`) ref, but then again it might not and have to generate an extra dereference.